# NSManagedObjectContext attributes of object nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to work with core data and already am able to store records of my class "Event.m". An event has a timestamp an a note.

But as i try to read all entries in my table view to display them, I see that every timestamp and note is nil (debug). Strange thing is, that my array I get has the right size (number of entries) and also the table rows are created (only no note si visible).

Here some of my code:

```
- (void)fetchRecords {

    // Define our table/entity to use
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    // Setup the fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    // Define how we will sort the records
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    // Fetch the records and handle an error
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (!mutableFetchResults) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching data.");
    }
    // Save our fetched data to an array
    [self setEventArray: mutableFetchResults];

    NSLog(@"Records found: %i", [eventArray count]);
}
```

And this is where I save my object:

```
- (void) saveEntry: (NSString *) note
{
    Event *event = (Event *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [event setTimeStamp: [NSDate date]];
    [event setNote:@"test"];

    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not save entry.");
    }
    NSLog(@"Entry saved.");

    [eventArray insertObject:event atIndex:0];
}
```

Note that there are two different views, from which I access Core Data.

And this is where I get my MOC in this views:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

}
```

[Here I was reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199143/core-data-attribute-changes-to-nil-arc-related), that it could come frome the MOC itself. This is how I hold my variable in SecondViewController.h

```
#import "Event.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *eventArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventArray;

- (void) fetchRecords;

@end
```

And in my .m file I have:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext, eventArray;
```

Then I call `fetchRecords`.

Any ideas why I have this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code where you configure your tableViewCells? That might be the problem.

Comment: I just figured out what was wrong. I missed one line of code at my request. After this I was able to access the attributes. I will post as answer

Answer (score 0):

I was missing one line of code, concerning the request:

```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [request setEntity:entity];
   [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

After adding the last line I was able to access all attributes.

Comment: That should make no difference. Even if the objects are fetched as faults, the properties are retrieved from the store when you access them.

Comment: But it really does. As soon as i delete this line I'm getting null again

Comment: Well, it looks equally strange to me as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675297/nsmanagedobjectcontext-nil-when-calling-second-time and its "solution" :-) - Are you working with multiple managed object contexts? If not: Are you sure that the MOC is created only *once* in the delegate?

Comment: I use the code from above 'viewDidLoad' twice. In both of my ViewControllers. Each of it has an own MOC ivar which is set

Comment: The question is if the MOC is created only once in the AppDelegate or not. If you add an NSLog() statement in the `managedObjectContext` method of the application delegate - how often is it called?

Comment: From both screens. But the same inctance is returned.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674739/two-questions-concerning-core-data

Comment: OK. I am 99% sure that `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO` should make no difference, but I cannot see an obvious error in your code so far.